# Background Color Fill Animation Ends in Offset

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to "fill" a circle when a user clicks on it. The main issue is that when the animation ends, it's offset on the top by just a little bit. I've tried to add a `margin-top: -1px` to it but it's then offset on the bottom!

I'm open to any suggestion to make the animation smoother but my main question is: Why is the end result offset from the top a tiny bit and how can I fix it?

```css
#searchOptions label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
#searchOptions label .circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
#searchOptions label .circle:before {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
}
#searchOptions label .txt {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
#searchOptions input[type=radio] {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
#searchOptions input[type=radio]:checked + label .circle:before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: fillRadio ease-in 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fillRadio {
  0% {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 1%;
    height: 1%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0%;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="searchOptions">
  <input type="radio" name="searchType" value="option1" id="option1" />
  <label for="option1"><span class="circle"></span>  <span class="txt">Option 1</span>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" name="searchType" value="option2" id="option2" />
  <label for="option2"><span class="circle"></span>  <span class="txt">Option 2</span>
  </label>
</div>
<!-- id="searchOptions" -->
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L407ebnb/) if anyone would rather use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem comes from a dimensiion of 15px and top of 50% -> that gives a fractional size

I have changed the size to 16px, that is even:

```css
#searchOptions label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
#searchOptions label .circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
#searchOptions label .circle:before {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
}
#searchOptions label .txt {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
#searchOptions input[type=radio] {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
#searchOptions input[type=radio]:checked + label .circle:before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: fillRadio ease-in 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fillRadio {
  0% {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 1%;
    height: 1%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0%;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="searchOptions">
  <input type="radio" name="searchType" value="option1" id="option1" />
  <label for="option1"><span class="circle"></span>  <span class="txt">Option 1</span>
  </label>

  <input type="radio" name="searchType" value="option2" id="option2" />
  <label for="option2"><span class="circle"></span>  <span class="txt">Option 2</span>
  </label>
</div>
<!-- id="searchOptions" -->
```